# How can I get Visual Studio Code's Dark Modern Java color syntax in IntelliJ

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

The default theme in VS Code is dark modern:

[image: VS Code default theme]

Example Java:

[image]

I like how this shows Java code with the yellow method names and the method parameters with their own distinctive color.

But my main IDE is IntelliJ, where I use the dark color scheme.
Example Java:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions about how I can use (free) plugins to add VS Code's Java syntax coloring scheme to IntelliJ?

Comment: Can you explain what I did wrong to get a -1?  I added some example pictures to improve the question.

Comment: Might not be easy, but you have the capability to set up your own now: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html#share-color-scheme

Comment: just like you can create a theme for VSC create one for IntelliJ, borrow the colors from the theme you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a really nice looking theme plugin you can use for IntelliJ called “**nightfall**”, and based on your first picture, it will give syntax highlighting of a similar shade / similar hues to that.

Comment: Thanks, I've installed that, it looks good! https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16142-nightfall-theme

Answer (score 1):

You can [customize syntax highlighting](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html#customize-color-scheme) and enable [semantic highlighting](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html#semantic-highlighting).

Or search and use similar themed extensions (might take many trials)。